# Error when exporting R table to excel using group_by

Tags: r, group-by

I am writing a function that will create a table from a dataframe using the `kable()` function, then export it to excel using the `writexl` library.

However I get an error with `summarise()` and `group_by()` function:

```
show_data <- function(df,col1,col2){

    myTable <- df %>%  
      filter(!is.na(col1),!is.na(col2)) %>% 
      group_by(col2, col1) %>% 
      summarise(subjects = n()) %>% 
      mutate(percent = round(subjects / sum(subjects, na.rm = TRUE)* 100, 1)) %>% select(-subjects) %>% 
      spread(col2,percent)
    names(myTable) <- c(col1,"col",col2)
    MyTable %>% a
    rrange(desc(col2)) %>%  
    kable(caption = paste(col1,"_",col2))

}
```

Error messages:
***Error: Can't extract columns that don't exist.
x Column `foo` doesn't exist.***

and

***Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.

- Column `columnTwo` is not found.
- Column `columnOne` is not found.***

Also, I would like to export a resulting table (via kable()) from R to Excel without having to repeat the same lines of code. Is this possible?

```
show_data <- function(df,col1,col2){

    myTable <- df %>%  
      filter(!is.na(col1),!is.na(col2)) %>% 
      group_by(col2, col1) %>% 
      summarise(subjects = n()) %>% 
      mutate(percent = round(subjects / sum(subjects, na.rm = TRUE)* 100, 1)) %>% select(-subjects) %>% 
      spread(col2,percent)
    names(myTable) <- c(col1,"col",col2)
    MyTable %>% a
    rrange(desc(col2)) %>%  
    kable(caption = paste(col1,"_",col2))

    myTable <- df %>%  
      filter(!is.na(col1),!is.na(col2)) %>% 
      group_by(col2, col1) %>% 
      summarise(subjects = n()) %>% 
      mutate(percent = round(subjects / sum(subjects, na.rm = TRUE)* 100, 1)) %>% select(-subjects) %>% 
      spread(col2,percent)
    names(myTable) <- c(col1,"col",col2)
    MyTable %>% 
    arrange(desc(col2)) %>%  
    write_xlsx(results.xlsx")


}
```

`show_data(my_data,"column_one","column_two")`

Comment: I think you are going to have some trouble with your non-standard eval. You need to have some `{{col1}}` calls or `!!enquo(col1)`.

Comment: Also it will be tough to troubleshoot without some data. try `dput(head(df))`

Comment: I suspect that this has nothing to do with `write_xlsx`, nor with `knitr::kable`, which suggests that [tag:kable] is not needed and the question itself can be simplified to just enough to reproduce the error. Since we don't have your data, it is currently difficult to provide actionable help, especially since the error citing `'foo' doesn't exist` is referring to a column that is referenced nowhere else. Further, this is about your use of `dplyr` so [tag:rstudio] is not appropriate.

Comment: FYI, `tidyr::spread` and `gather` have been superseded by the much more powerful `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` (same package). I urge you to consider updating your code, it is often not very difficult and will pay dividends when `spread` is eventually deprecated.